# How to define a matrix before creating it?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, input

how can I define this matrix prior to or after it's been created so that I can then perform other operations on it?
The problem is that the matrix is created after the user input so I can't just type it in myself.
the n is asking user for a number that is then used to create a matrix of n x n dimensions.

```
n = int(input("number: "))
for row in range(0, size):
  for col in range(0, size):
    if (row == col):
      print("1 ", end=" ")
    else:
      print("0 ", end=" ")
```

Comment: The question is unclear to me. Maybe you want something like `matrix = np.empty((size, size))`. You can fill it with `matrix[y, x] = value`

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

n = int(input("number: "))
a = np.zeros((n, n), int)
np.fill_diagonal(a, 1)
print(a)
```

**EDIT**

As @Reinderien said in a comment section it's easier to do this with np.eye() function

```
import numpy as np

n = int(input("number: "))
a = np.eye(n)
print(a)
```

Comment: Why not just use `np.eye()`?

Comment: np.eye() is a better solution; I'll update the answer